# c# see Hebrew on console when reading serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, hebrew

I'm trying to see Hebrew on my CMD but i get gibrish...

I have setup my new encoding

but I still can't see Hebrew fonts....

this is the full code :

```
try
{
    sp.Open();
    while (true)
    {       
        sp.Read(rec, 0, rec.Length);
        for (int x = 0; x<rec.Length; x++)
        {              
            Encoding ansiencoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
            Console.OutputEncoding = ansiencoding;
            resualt = Convert.ToInt32(rec[x]); //HEX value as string 
            hex = resualt.ToString("X");// DEC value of hex
            byte[] ByteMessage = ansiencoding.GetBytes(hex);
            string HexMessage = BitConverter.ToString(ByteMessage);
            char c = Convert.ToChar(resualt);
            string test = ansiencoding.GetString(ByteMessage);
            if (resualt == 0)              
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else
            {                  
                Console.WriteLine(hex + "  " + HexMessage + "    " + ansiencoding.GetString(ByteMessage) + "   ---->   " + c + "--------" + test);

            }  
        }
    }//end while

}//end try
```

and this is the console output -

2E  32-45    2E   ---->   .--------2E

31  33-31    31   ---->   1--------31

42  34-32    42   ---->   B--------42

3  33    3   ---->   --------3

E8  45-38    E8   ---->   ?--------E8

1B  31-42    1B   ---->   --------1B

31  33-31    31   ---->   1--------31

31  33-31    31   ---->   1--------31

39  33-39    39   ---->   9--------39

20  32-30    20   ---->    --------20

EF  45-46    EF   ---->   ?--------EF

E1  45-31    E1   ---->   ?--------E1

E5  45-35    E5   ---->   ?--------E5

E0  45-30    E0   ---->   ?--------E0

F8  46-38    F8   ---->   ?--------F8

20  32-30    20   ---->    --------20

EC  45-43    EC   ---->   ?--------EC

E2  45-32    E2   ---->   ?--------E2

E3  45-33    E3   ---->   ?--------E3

A  41    A   ---->         --------A

1B  31-42    1B   ---->   --------1B

31  33-31    31   ---->   1--------31

F8  46-38    F8   ---->   ?--------F8

E3  45-33    E3   ---->   ?--------E3

E9  45-39    E9   ---->   ?--------E9

E9  45-39    E9   ---->   ?--------E9

F0  46-30    F0   ---->   ?--------F0

F9  46-39    F9   ---->   ?--------F9

20  32-30    20   ---->    --------20

EC  45-43    EC   ---->   ?--------EC

E0  45-30    E0   ---->   ?--------E0

20  32-30    20   ---->    --------20

36  33-36    36   ---->   6--------36

32  33-32    32   ---->   2--------32

20  32-30    20   ---->    --------20

E5  45-35    E5   ---->   ?--------E5

F7  46-37    F7   ---->   ÷--------F7

when I open simple serial port emulator and read the data - 
I can see the hebrew fonts

my windows have hebrew fonts in the console (it's not windows issue..)

*
 another thing I have notice is -when I look at the windows 1255 table 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255

it's OK - E7 E5 is a consist with hebrew fonts

Thanks ,

Comment: nope , doesn't help me - what else?

Comment: If you have a Console application, you need to add a Font that supports Hebrew characters. The standard Fonts (Consolas and Lucida Console) don't. Courier New does. You can add it in the Registry here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`. If you already have a Font that can output Hebrew chars, than it depends on the source. If it is a document or a Web page, use `Encoding.Unicode` (if the text is inserted in a String variable) or `Encoding.UTF8` (the use of this depends on Encoding used whan trans-coding the original CodePage).

Comment: the data is coming from serial device  , so what I have to change in the code?

Comment: Post a full sample of the output you receive from the serial port. Anyway, it looks like those characters codes actually directly map to a Hewbew CodePage (1255 being the main), thus your conversion method should be ok. You didn't say if the Console in that OS has a Font that can print them. If the current OS language is not Hebrew, that you don't. Assign a Console Font as described before. Courier New is a possible choice. Open the Registry key and verify if it's there. If not, insert a new string named "000" (the number of `0` is the max existing +1) and write Courier New as the new value.

Comment: @Jimi - I have updated my question , please take a look now

Comment: i think my problem is in the printing - because even if i want to print Hex 151 , 133 ,140  which is ascii for Hebrew - i still get Gibrish... how could it be?

Comment: Try `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");`

Comment: I have this at start.... where do you want to me to try it ?